# How to inline svgs in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to load svgs inline with angular 7.

So far I tried:

```
import icon = require('./icon.svg');
```

results in `icon.svg` due to file-loader

```
import icon = require('raw-loader?!./icon.svg');
```

results in `__webpack_public_path__ + "icon.svg";`

which is the same as:

```
import * as icon3 from 'raw-loader?!./icon.svg';
```

and

```
import icon4 from 'raw-loader?!./icon.svg';
```

will become undefined.

However renaming the `icon.svg` in something like `icon.foo` and then loading the icon with:

```
import * as icon from 'raw-loader?!./icon.foo';
```

and the appropriate type in `typings.d.ts` results in the anticipated behavior and the variable icon holds the inlined content.

For me it seams like the file-loader somehow precedes the raw loader. Changing `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/common.js` to load svgs like htmls in the rules works as well. But this is not a way to go.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to load svg and just display it?

Comment: I want to inline them, found a solution though...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the rule is already defined, it has to be overruled by putting two `!!` at the beginning of the loader:

```
import icon = require('!!raw-loader?!./icon.svg');
```

**ADDITION 2021**

it should work without require ... do not forget the typings.d.ts

```
import icon from '!!raw-loader?!./icon.svg';
```

See: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/ at the very bottom

> Beware, if you already define loader(s) for extension(s) in webpack.config.js you should use:
>
> '!!raw-loader!./file.css'; // Adding `!!` to a request will disable all loaders specified in the configuration

Comment: despite the information quoted on the raw-loader github page, this does NOT work with the latest version of raw-loader (2.0.0) and Angular CLI. it produces a compile error.

Comment: @KimGentes but does angular cli work with raw-loader 2.0.0 in general?

Comment: That is exactly the question I am trying to determine. I have found no one who has used the new raw-loader with latest Angular CLI. I would love to hear if someone has it working, because I'd like to know how they are now referencing the raw-loader package to load their data files.

Comment: @KimGentes, the "above" (`const logo = require('!!raw-loader?!../assets/logo.svg') as string;`) works for me in Angular 7 CLI. In Angular 8 CLI I don't have any compilation errors, but the result is a Module. So the following works: `const logo = require('!!raw-loader?!../assets/logo.svg').default as string;`.

Comment: Better yet, this works in Angular 8 CLI: `import logo from '!!raw-loader!../assets/logo.svg';`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a `.ts` file

**my-svg.ts**

```
export const mySVG = `<svg></svg>`;
```

Then you can import it normally

```
import {mySVG} from 'path/to/file/my-svg.ts'
```

Comment: Thanks, I have like 100s of svgs in a legacy app. That would not be a solution

Comment: Oh, then this won't be a solution.